# How to enter text automatically into datagridview in vb.net once a certain condition is met?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm a beginner in vb.net. I'm trying to develop a reminder system connected to a database in phpMyAdmin using visual basics where the text 'EXPIRE' will be displayed in a column of a datagridview control if an item's expiry date in the database matches with today's date. I have a total of 10 columns in the control and the column I want the text to be displayed is the 10th column.

I have already connected the control to the database and wrote a query of which field in the database table I would like to compare with today's date. I think I need to use an "if...else" condition to compare and display the text, but I'm not familiar with the syntax, hence I'm now stuck. Please help!

```
Public Sub insertStatus()
    Dim query As String
    connection = New MySqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=luce;password=root;database=chemicalinventoryrecord"

    query = "select expiryDate from chemicalinventory;"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    'stuck at this point
    If Date.Today = query Then
       dgvChemical.Columns(10).
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a read here for guidance on retrieving data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could put it in the SQL: `SELECT a, b, c, IF(now() > ItemDate, 'EXPIRED', '') AS Expiry FROM TableName`

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the comment. I tried the codes you posted, but I did a little modifying.     query = "insert into chemicalinventory (status) values (Expired) where Now() >= expiryDate "

However, I still couldn't get the text to appear in the table. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The question asks about getting some text into the DGV...that s different than inserting into the DB

Comment: @Plutonix I see. What if I have the program insert the text into the DB first? Then, with the connection I have made with the DGV, the text will appear in the DGV. Would that work?

Comment: Its almost never a good idea to store something which can be easily calculated.  The SQL I gave shows how to create a column with that text as part of the SELECT which is what you asked - it doesnt need to be in the DB to be in the DGV.  You could also *just* select the expired ones using a `WHERE( ExpireDate < Now())`.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh,  I see. I must have misinterpreted the codes. XD I'm not very familiar with mysql coding in vb.net because I just started self learning it. So the SELECT a, b, c are columns I want selected from the database?