# For Each loop for mysql database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a reminder that notifies users the number of days before a chemical expires. I'm trying to retrieve the data in my database using **ForEach** loop, but I can't get the syntax right.

`For Each chemicalName as DataRow In chemicalinventory.Rows`

For some reason, the error: name '`chemicalinventory`' not declared keeps popping up.

From what I seen online, that is supposed to be the table name. Am I coding it wrong? Please answer if you know what's the error.

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `chemicalinventory`?  If you never declared it, then that would explain why it's not declared.

Comment: @David `chemicalinventory` is the name of a table in mysql database. Is there a way to declare it as a variable? I'm trying to go through each data in the table.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a tutorial on how to interact with a database in .NET.  Application code and databases are entirely separate entities.  You can't simply refer to a database table as a variable and expect the code to know how to find that table.

Comment: How do you connect to MySQL? Do you use ADO.Net directly or some kind of an ORM?

Comment: @David Oh, I see. Are there any good online guides that you can point me to? I can't seem to find any good ones that explain in detail how to do this.
PS: I'm new to vb.net coding.

Comment: There are many many posts here on how to work with a DB - [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39546528/1070452) shows you already know a bit.  Do please read [Ask] and take the [tour] to learn how SO really works

Comment: @Shadow I'm using vb.net.

Comment: @Lucynda: *Surely* you're able to find a tutorial *somewhere* on how to use a database in .NET.  There are *countless* tutorials and examples online.  A cursory Google search for something like "vb.net database tutorial" will find what you're looking for, and much more.  As for Stack Overflow, questions asking for off-site resources and links are off-topic.

Comment: Vb.net is a programming language. ADO.Net and ORMs are techniques to connect to a database from the chosen language

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just directly start querying tables in this manner. You need to select your data from the database table and use it to fill a `DataTable`. You can then loop through the rows of this DataTable to get what you're after.

There are many ways to do that, but here is a very basic setup - granted, you'd need to specify a connection string in your Web.Config, and modify the SQL query to be relative to your needs.

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING").ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM chemicals"
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

Dim DataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd

Dim chemicalInventory As New DataTable()
DataAdapter.Fill(chemicalInventory)

For each row as DataRow in chemicalInventory.rows
   Response.write(row.item("column_name"))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I needed. Now to make it work fully for what I am trying to accomplish.